# The primefaces text editor does not show in a tab

Tags: jquery, primefaces, tabs, text-editor

The text editor I am trying to add is on the second tab in a page. When I am adding the text editor just below the tabs in the page [Text editor added in page just below the tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9QLM.jpg), it is get initialized and is visible in the first tab itself. but it is not visible for the second tab.

How do I make it visible on the second tab? is it some size issue or an initialization issue?

The image below is of the when I adding the text editor just below the tabs

the code I am using for the this is :

```
<li class="tab-item"><a data-toggle="tab" class="tutorialsTab" href="#tutorials">Tutorials Tips <i class="material-icons done">done</i> </a></li>
</ul>
<p:textEditor widgetVar="ed" id="labDescription" class="primefacesEditorTesting"
                                 height="100"
                                style="margin-bottom:10px" />
                        </h:form>
```

In the second case, where I am adding a new text editor in a form in second tab, in between the option of timezone and Lab description it is rendred as depicted in the following image: 
[The text editor added in the second tab in a different form while renders on a button click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvvx2.jpg)

the code I am using for this tab is :

```
<p:textEditor widgetVar="ed" id="labDescription" class="primefacesEditorTesting"
                                 height="100"
                                style="margin-bottom:10px" />

                    <div class="row form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 ">
                            <h:outputText for="lab-description" value="Lab Description" />
                                <h:inputTextarea id="lab-description" styleClass="form-control" a:placeholder="eg: What are the goals and objectives for you and your team with this Lab?"
                                    value="#{labManagedBean.lab.description}" style="resize: none"  rows="6"/>
                        </div>
```

Comment: please read [ask] and [mcve] and post version info

Comment: @Kukeltje Please review.

Comment: Please read [mcve] carefully. This is not one. I did not downvote (yet) but please also read http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Comment: Can you please share the code?